# Translate one line from C to Python

Tags: python, c, raycasting

I'm currently following a tutorial to program raycasting, the tutorial is in C and I'm rewriting it in Python, but I can't understand the following line and so can't translate it in python :

```
float aTan = -1/tan(ra);
ry = (((int)py>>6)<<6-0.0001;
rx = (py-ry)*aTan+px;
```

Where ry and rx are the y and x coordinates of the intersection between, I think, the first horizontal line and the ray.
Moreover, ra is the angle of the ray.
The lines with aTan and rx are just maths so I understand them but the writing of ry is not familiar for a python student like me, could you enlighten me ?

Comment: ...and you expect people to guess what `ra` and `py` are? Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ">>" operator is the right shift, so integer division by power of two.

Numerically

```
ry = (((int)py>>6)<<6-0.0001;
```

is equivalent to

```
ry = (py // 64) * 64 - 0.0001
```

(since `2^6 == 64`)

Comment: Python has `>>` and `<<` too.

Comment: ohhhh thanks a lot ! it's crystal clear now

Comment: @MarkRansom  That is why I wrote 'numerically' equivalent. Truncating division // also works for float so we spare the `int` cast. But yes, in principle the same line would work in Python too, except for the cast to int.

Comment: My point is that the statement is *almost* valid Python as-is, no need to introduce extra confusion by explaining how right-shift is equivalent to division.  `ry = (int(py)>>6)<<6-0.0001` is much easier to relate back to the original code.

Comment: P.S. converting a division result to int isn't always identical to truncating division.  Compare `int(-1/2)` to `-1//2`.